# Deserializing JSON list into list of objects with Flexjson

Tags: java, json, serialization, flexjson

I'm trying to deserialize the following json:

```js
{ "books": [ {"id":"1","name":"book 1"}, {"id":"2","name":"book 2"} ] }
```

Into a List. It worked before with this json:

```js
[ {"id":"1","name":"book 1"}, {"id":"2","name":"book 2"} ] }
```

Using this code:

```java
List<Book> items = new JSONDeserializer<ArrayList<Book>>()
.use("values", Book.class).deserialize(json, ArrayList.class);
```

But now after looking at multiple examples I am at a loss, is it possible to deserialize directly into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I found an acceptable solution, although I do not know how optimal it is

```java
List<Book> items = new JSONDeserializer<Map<String,List<Book>>>().
use("values.values", Book.class).deserialize(json, Map.class).get("books");
```

Will result in a list of books. If anyone maybe have a more "proper" solution feel free to comment.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the sample from @vikke I successfully applied the deserialization of a list of longs.

```
List<Long> idsLong = new JSONDeserializer<List<Long>>().use("values", Long.class).deserialize("[123,456,789]");
```

Answer (score 1):

under flexjson 1.9.2 below

List list = new JSONDeserializer>().use(null, ArrayList.class).use("values", Long.class).deserialize( episodeIds );
        System.out.println( list );

Answer (score -3):

try this. Its working with me.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

List<Book> lstBook = jss.Deserialize<List<Book>>("your string");
```

Comment: Isnt JavaScriptSerializer a C# class? If it is available for Java, what lib do I need to import?

Comment: Yup, Its a C# class, for java try this link http://code.google.com/p/json-io/. I have not tested it but seems it will work.